# Python Herencia: Cómo pasar una propiedad de clase Padre como parámetro en un método Hijo?

Tags: python-3.x, poo, herencia

Estoy aprendiendo Python, pero estoy teniendo problemas. Quiero crear un objeto que herede una probabilidad, por ejemplo de 60% de que salga True o false. Pero cuando ejecuto el método que calcula las opciones (True, False) y las probabilidades, en este caso 60% de 100, tengo un error:

p.calcular(opciones, super(_probabilidades)) me da este error: p.calcular(opciones, super(_probabilidades))
NameError: name 'opciones' is not defined... qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
class Probabilidad():

def __init__(self):
    self._probabilidades = []

def select_prob(self, dif):

    if (dif == "60"):
        
        self._probabilidades = [0.6, 1]
    else:
        self._probabilidades = [0.4, 1]
        
class TrueorFalse(Probabilidad): 

def __init__(_probabilidades):
    super().__init__()
    

def calcular(opciones, _probabilidades):
    opciones = [True, False]
    probAcumuladas = []
    aux = 0
    for p in _probabilidades_p:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)

    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]

   p = TrueorFalse()
   p.select_prob('60')
   p.calcular(opciones, super(_probabilidades))
```

Comment: En `calcular`, `opciones` aparece tanto un parámetro de la función como una lista. No puede ser ambas cosas.

Answer (score 1):

#### error NameError: name 'opciones' is not defined

Estas pasandole al método la variable opciones peró no está definida. No existe.

#### error de concepto método `super()`

Quieres acceder al argumento `_probabilidades`

Este argumento ya existe, no hace falta llamar a `super()`. Substituye esa llamada `super(_probabilidades)` por `p._probabilidades`.

```
   p.calcular(opciones, p._probabilidades))
```

El argumento ya se ha inicializado, ya existe. Estás confundiendo el uso del método especial `super()`.  Te serviría en la programacion de la clase `TrueorFalse` para acceder a algún `atributo` de su padre. De hecho, ya lo has hecho.  En el método `__init__()`. Estás llamando al **init**() padre/madre des del hijo/hija. Ahí si hay un uso correcto

#### otros

Revisa el sentido del parámetro opciones de la función calcular, como comenta un compañero, manca sentido lógico.

Veo mucha manca de lógica en el código. Es muy posible que no te vaya a funcionar, pero con mi respuesta intento que puedas corregir algunos de los errores.